# Google Sheets: Finding the date for when it first hits a million

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, vlookup

[image]

I am trying to find a formula that will tell me when the person will hit a million dollars. I want on an empty cell that will tell me, **"You will hit a million dollars on, August 2050"**,
Since August 2050 will be the first month & year for the million dollar to exceed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer, we have to make some guesses about the location of your data as well as the country you are currently in.

```
=VLOOKUP(1000000,SORT(SPLIT({FLATTEN(B4:S15&"|"&A4:A15&" "&B3:S3);FLATTEN(B17:S28&"|"&A17:A28&" "&B16:S16)},"|",0,0)),2)
```

edited from original based on updated info from OP.

Comment: Hello, I have edited edited this post to show the reference a little better. When I enter in your formula, it shows the wrong date and also does not include the years in Row 16

Comment: @den I've updated/edited my formula based on your edits/comments

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I needed, but it's resulting in the month before it hits 1 million. (7/1/23) When it should be 8/1/23. The formula I put so far is "=VLOOKUP(1000000,SORT(SPLIT({FLATTEN(B4:S15&"|"&A4:A15&" "&B3:S3);FLATTEN(B17:S28&"|"&A17:A28&" "&B16:S16)},"|",0,0)),2)+31
" in which I added "+31. Should I keep this, since it results in 8/1/23?

Comment: @den
no probably not, can you share a screenshot of the data that's resulting in that? because the data you shared doesn't hit 1000000 anywhere near 8/1/23

Comment: I just updated this post, the bottom picture is where it shows your formula but with the added +31 at the end of the formula which results in 8/1/2050

Comment: I didn't mean 8/1/23, I meant 8/1/50!!! I'm sorry

Comment: @den i understand now, and sure, adding 31 will work always.  But...
It's entirely possible that you don't need the table or the formula at all...
what is the compounding formula in each cell that is giving you those values? It would be simple algebra to derive a much simpler formula to give you the month of $1,000,000 using that.